# How to perform nested sorting in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have following data:

`id      name        score
1       sam               5
2       sam               1
3       jerry             6 
4       jerry             2
5       sam               3`

I want it like

`id      name        score
3       jerry             6
4       jerry             2
1       sam               5
5       sam               3
2       sam               1`

**I want to perform nested sorting in this table I want result which is sorted by similar lastname and those last name is sorted by score**

but it not working and giving me wrong result can anyone tell me how to do this??

Comment: Why are the scores different in your output than the source table?

Comment: monthly_sales_target  isn't a column in your example data.

Comment: jerry has other id's in your desired output. The column names of the shown tables don't have much in common with the sort columns in your SQL query. I guess by trying to make it easy to understand, you missed the target somewhet

Comment: sorry for that typo but you get the idea

Comment: wait i'll edit it

Comment: make sure the question is correct without typos or missing columns..

Comment: Just exchange the two columns in the order by clause will do the job.
I'm not sure your query is correct.

Comment: Ohh I get it Thanks Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why do you join this table "ex" with itself? And why do you join on a non-unique column lastname?

Probably you need a query like

```
select id, lastname, monthly_sales_target
  from ex
 order by lastname, monthly_sales_target;
```

This will sort your result by lastname and within lastname by monthly_sales_target.